# SiriKit for iOS Email App

Tags: ios, email, siri, sirikit

I'm creating a 3rd party email app and I wanted to know if it's possible to use SiriKit as part of the Messaging domain? 
Will it be approved by Apple?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because developer-centric questions about application stores are considered off-topic here on SO as discussed in [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Were you able to invoke the message intent using "email" keyword rather than the "message" keyword?